# Dynamic header with subreport in JasperSoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a report that contains many subreport. Each one has a different width, so I need to set an header that takes the length of the widest subreport.

I added a textfield (like a title) into the "Page Header" band (also in the "Title" band, but the result is the same) and I tried to set different properties (Stretch Type, Detail Overflows ...) but the textfield width remains static.

What is the properties that I failed?

[image]

How you can see the title is the blue row, but his width is not the same of the subreport width below..

.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2016-08-09T14:35:08 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reportAutocertificazioniDocProbaSpesa" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="842" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="776a21e5-d931-4e5f-be08-e1796cec8b1c">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="collectionFatture" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_PROBA_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="CUP" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="collectionDetermine" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
    <parameter name="collectionMandati" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
    <parameter name="collectionAL" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
    <parameter name="collectionANL" class="java.util.ArrayList"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_AUTOCERT_DIR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="importoVociLavoriQuotaMIUR" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        </band>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="842" height="60" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" backcolor="#009FC5" uuid="f5a3fea3-1efe-416a-8ee0-86b2fb2e1726">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Dettaglio autocertificazioni e documentazione probatoria - "+$P{CUP}+" - "+$P{ente}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="60">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="841" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="daa09642-95c6-4e72-bba3-89c9f6dd6b93">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PROBA_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ente">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ente}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="CUP">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CUP}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{collectionFatture})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PROBA_DIR} + "reportDocumentazioneProbatoriaFTXLS.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="60">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="841" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="123b41d9-6094-4ca3-9d28-f30935ef4423"/>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PROBA_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ente">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ente}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="CUP">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CUP}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{collectionDetermine})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PROBA_DIR} + "reportDocumentazioneProbatoriaDTXLS.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="60">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="841" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="53f43657-f8fa-4cc3-aaf4-228e3d790d5b"/>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PROBA_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ente">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ente}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="CUP">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CUP}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{collectionMandati})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_PROBA_DIR} + "reportDocumentazioneProbatoriaMQXLS.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="60">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="841" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="1aa39919-9589-4354-8b35-ce05cce8aaeb">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="importoVociLavoriQuotaMIUR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{importoVociLavoriQuotaMIUR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{collectionAL})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_AUTOCERT_DIR} + "reportALXLS.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="60">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="840" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="be9393d0-79f1-4f40-b163-42334202e699">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="importoVociLavoriQuotaMIUR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{importoVociLavoriQuotaMIUR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{collectionANL})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_AUTOCERT_DIR} + "reportANLXLS.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I don't understand the point. Why would you set a header as high as a subreport? Seems like a waste of space.

Comment: @tobi6, Not "as high" but "wide as" the widest subreport (maybe I badly explained myself)

Comment: @DavideFruci You should post at least the image. The posting the *jrxml* will be also good

Comment: @AlexK, done it man.

Comment: Would it be an option to put the header into the subreport?

Comment: @DavideFruci I can't understand is which subreport is included dynamic?, so you can't understand what width it will have?, if so you need to do different headers.. but I have a feeling that I have not understand your report layout correctly.

Comment: It appears your detail band has a height="60" only but no width value.